# How to fix deprecated URL helper action in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 4.2.0 app this bit of code...

```
link_to "Show projects as CSV", projects_path(params.merge(:format => :csv))
```

...produces the following warning in the logs:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling URL helpers with string keys controller, action is deprecated. Use symbols instead.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Probably related to this: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18609

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually need to move some params across?
If not, then this should work

```
link_to "Show projects as CSV", projects_path(format: "csv")
```

Your problem is that params in your helper is referencing ActionController::Params object, something like:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"pages", "action"=>"home"} permitted: false>
```

You shouldn't need to add all the params like that, simply passing format: "csv" will work.

If you got any additional params that you need to move across in the link, you can do something along the lines of:

```
link_to "Show projects as CSV", projects_path(foo: params[:foo], bar: params[:bar], format: "csv")
```

Comment: Allowing any arbitrary param to be echoed back is a really poor practice which can be exploited.

Comment: Surprisingly `link_to "Show projects as CSV", projects_path(format: "csv")` really works! Weird that I haven't used it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should not pass through params between requests (see params.merge and cross site scripting), but instead slice the params you need for your new request and merge the new ones:

```
@csv_prms = params.slice(:param1, :param2).merge( format: :csv )
```